# How to get the name from an ID in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.company_id %>
<% end %>
```

I want to get the company_id's name somehow from the other table.

I've tried `<%= contact.company_id.collect(&:name) %>`

without success can i get some help here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# Models
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <%= contact.company.name %>
<% end %>
```