# In Rails, I can't get the referenced name to show from an id, undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display the abbreviation of a state inside a company view that is referenced via an id from another table. I think my problem is with the `belongs_to` and `has_one`, but I can't be sure.

I inserted a foreign key in my **migration for companies** to reference states like so:

```
add_foreign_key :companies, :states, column:  :sid, primary_key: :id
```

My **models** looks like this:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company 
  ...
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :state 
  ...
end
```

So in my `index` view for companies, I cycle through my companies like so:

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  ...
  <%= company.city %>
  <%= company.sid %>
  <%= company.zip %>
```

Which is fine & dandy, but it gives me the id for the state like so:

```
name           city        sate   zip
Company One    Some City   44     12345
Company Two    Some City   44     12345
```

I would like to display the state abbreviation instead. So I changed the state referencing line in the view as follows:

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  ...
  <%= company.city %>
  <%= company.state.abbrev %>  # I changed this one
  <%= company.zip %>
```

And now i get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'states.company_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `states`.* FROM `states` WHERE `states`.`company_id` = 2 LIMIT 1
```

I'm not sure if my `belongs_to` and `has_one` are correct, but when I reverse them to this:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company 
  ...
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state 
  ...
end
```

I get this error instead:

```
undefined method `abbrev' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried the solution on the following link, which made me change the order of my relationships, but it just gave me a different error.

[How to get the name from an ID in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106564/how-to-get-the-name-from-an-id-in-another-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key column is named `sid`, not `state_id`, as Rails assumes it to be named by default. You need to override this defaults by setting column name in `foreign_key` option in your models.

Also you probably should interchange `belongs_to` and `has_one` in your models (based on foreign key placement in companies).

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company, foreign_key: :sid
 ...
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state, foreign_key: :sid
  ...
end
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Although, I used the second option where `State has_one Company` and `Company belongs_to State` and added the foreign_key to them.